# Implementation of Dickey-Fuller test in R

Tags: r, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

I'm working with Dickey-Fuller test.

The steps are as follows:

**Step 1:** Starting with model 3, test the significance of time trend. If it isn't significant, then go to step 2. If it is, then test the stationarity of model 3.

**Step 2:** Run model 2 (test the significant of drift, or constant). If it isn't significant, then go to step 3. If it is, then test the stationarity of model 2.

**Step 3:** Run model 1 (test the stationarity)

However, my code doesn't run correctly. What mistakes did I make?
[image]

```
library(urca)
data("PepperPrice")
Trend1=ur.df(PepperPrice[,"white"],type="trend",lags=0)
Trend2=ur.df(PepperPrice[,"white"],type="drift",lags=0)
Trend3=ur.df(PepperPrice[,"white"],type="none",lags=0)
summa1=summary(Trend1)
summa2=summary(Trend2)
summa3=summary(Trend3)

if summa1@teststat[,"phi3"] < summa1@cval["phi3","5pct"] {
    if summa2@teststat[,"phi1"]<summa2@cval["phi1","5pct"] {
        if summa3@teststat < summa3@cval["tau1","5pct"] {
          "stationnaire"
          } else {
            "non stationnaire"
          }
    } else {
      if summa2@teststat[,"tau2"] < summa2@cval["tau2","5pct"] {
        "stationnaire"
      } else {
        "non stationnaire"
      }
    }
} else {
  if summa1@teststat[,"tau3"] < summa1@cval["tau3","5pct"] {
    "stationnaire"
  } else {
    "non stationnaire"
  }
}
```

**UPDATED:**this is the error occurred.

[image]

Comment: Proof-reading code is generally off-topic here. But out of curiosity, *how* does your code fail? I see that you miss some parentheses. You should use `if(condition){action}`.

Comment: I don't have your pepper data, but once I fixed the parentheses, the code at least did not break for a simple white noise and for a simple random walk.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've included the error I met in my post.

Comment: you must install package "AER" to have this data

Comment: Including parentheses where appropriate will help you get rid of the error.

Comment: it like function which you say: if(condition) {action} else {action}. I respect that. Can you help me? or have you orther method to run it? thanks advance

Comment: Example: do not use `if summa1@teststat[,"phi3"] < summa1@cval["phi3","5pct"] {` but instead use `if(summa1@teststat[,"phi3"] < summa1@cval["phi3","5pct"]){`. Notice that I added a pair of parentheses around the condition right after `if`. Do it wherever you use `if`, and it will work.

Comment: ok. that's right. this is my problem, it work. thanks you so much